# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent using web-terminal

Tags: node.js

i was trying to use web-terminal.. when i ran my server code, I got following error

```
Web-terminal accessible at http://127.0.0.1:1337/terminal

http.js:691
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home/praful/terminalcloud/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:63:22)
at redirect (/home/praful/terminalcloud/node_modules/web-terminal/lib/terminal.js:25:9)
at SendStream.<anonymous> (/home/praful/terminalcloud/node_modules/web-terminal/lib/terminal.js:90:21)
at SendStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at SendStream.redirect (/home/praful/terminalcloud/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:271:55)
at /home/praful/terminalcloud/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:321:41
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

My server side code is:

```
 var http        = require("http"),
    terminal    = require("web-terminal");

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello World\n");
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/");

terminal(app);
console.log("Web-terminal accessible at http://127.0.0.1:1337/terminal");
```

How i can resolve this problem.

Comment: I would open an issue reporting this error for the mantainers of that module. I've ran into the same problem: when accessing the URL `http://127.0.0.1:1337/terminal`, I see the same message in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this problem... I used "connect" module to create the server..

```
var connect = require('connect');
var terminal = require('web-terminal');
terminal(connect.createServer(
    connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8080));
```

Also copy the contents of "web" directory from web-terminal package into your server directory...
Now you can access the web terminal from http://'servername':8080/index.html